# cudaMemcpy image data with conversion from HWC to CHW

Tags: opencv, image-processing, cuda

Imagine that we have some OpenCV usual image Mat:

```
cv::Mat usual_image = cv::imread(...)
```

This image stored as HWC/NHWC array in memory.

If that possible to copy this image as CHW/NCHW (separated channel arrays, in sense) into cuda memory without super high cost cv::split?

Just for visualization HWC and CHW:
[image: Just for visualization]

Comment: probably. `cv::split` is cpu-side, hence slow. afaik there's `cv::cuda::split` (device-side), which should be a lot cheaper, and there's probably ways to do the conversion *during* transfer too. some related recipes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637162/how-cvmat-convert-to-nhcw-format and https://answers.opencv.org/question/191013/dnn-loading-of-models-and-order-of-channels/ -- when you use opencv's `dnn` module, it has various "blob" methods that should take care of this

Comment: If you have pre-allocated memory where you want to write, cv::cuda::split will be even worse than cpu version. Because there will exists intermediate cudamemalloc, which cost is huge.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this will be to copy the image as-is to the GPU, then [write a GPU kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012998/why-does-nvenc-sample-use-both-cumemcpyhtod-and-cumemcpy2d-to-copy-yuv-data/33018836#33018836) to split the data into 3 buffers.

A slower alternative would be to use 3 [calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803272/how-to-copy-variables-from-a-custom-class-array-on-host-into-a-float-array-on-de/20805680#20805680) to `cudaMemcpy2D` to copy the data from host to device, one call per plane.